# Popping one element from a RabbitMQ queue

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I have a queue, and I've stuffed some n elements from it.

I want to take 1 element from it, and then exit the callback.The `pika` examples all use a callback mechanism, which really does not make sense in the application structure.

Defining a callback as follows

```
def callback(...):
  do_data_thinggs(...)
  exit(0)
```

doesn't work, as the message stays in the queue

What's the usual idiom for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to look at the basic_get method on the channel, have a look at:

https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/03542ef616a2a849e8bfb0845427f50e741ea0c6/docs/examples/blocking_basic_get.rst for an example, this will block until a message is received.

Comment: @IanGoldby I've updated the link, hope that it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think this has to do with you not ACKing. 
take a look at this tutorial: [RabbitMQ tutorial 2](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html)